# How to add data from an SQLite Database into an ArrayList (Android)

Tags: android, sqlite, arraylist

I'm relatively new to Android and I was making a To-Do List application. I have a database containing a column of tasks. How can I put these tasks into an ArrayList and display it ?

```
helper = new TaskDBHelper(MainActivity.this);
        SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.query(TaskContract.TABLE, new String[]{TaskContract.Columns._ID,TaskContract.Columns.TASK}, null, null, null, null, null);

        arrayListToDo = new ArrayList<String>();

arrayAdapterToDo = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayListToDo);

        ListView listViewToDo = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewToDo);
        listViewToDo.setAdapter(arrayAdapterToDo);
```

Comment: You could iterate over your Cursor and add the tasks to your ArrayList but I'd suggest you to look into CursorAdapters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code

```
while (cursor.moveToNext()) {

arrayListToDo.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Your column name")));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the data in Array list :-

```html
ArrayList<String> arrayListToDo= new ArrayList<String>();  
//your query will returns cursor
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
  do {
    arrayListToDo.add(get you string from cursor);
  } while (cursor.moveToNext());
}
```

now add this aray list to your Adapter.

Answer (score 0):

get list data from database this is only overview

```
     ArrayList<String> data = databaseObject.GetList();
ListView listViewToDo = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewToDo);
arrayAdapterToDo = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, data);
listViewToDo.setAdapter(arrayAdapterToDo);


      ArrayList<String> GetList()
    {
        ArrayList<String> arrayListtemp= new ArrayList<String>();
        SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.query(TaskContract.TABLE, new String[]{TaskContract.Columns._ID,TaskContract.Columns.TASK}, null, null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                arrayListtemp.add("");// added your table value from database
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        return arrayListtemp;
    }
```