# Select all rows where Column x contains Value x

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

Hey I'm new at SQLite and have a problem with the `SELECT * * WHERE` clause.

I have a table like this:

**Trips**:

```
id      trip        lat         lon
1        1          50.0        50.0
2        1          50.1        50.1
3        1          50.2        50.2
4        2          50.3        50.3
5        2          50.4        50.4
```

I want to add the rows to an `ArrayList` of Data where trip = 1:

```
ArrayList<Data> DataList;

data = new Data(long id, int trip, double lat, double lon);
```

Thank you

Comment: and what is your problem exactly? You don't know how to get rows from SQLite using Android? You don't know what to write in the query? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Query should be something like `Select * from Trips WHERE trip = 1`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27523669/how-to-add-data-from-an-sqlite-database-into-an-arraylist-android

Comment: My problem is that I do not know how to go through the table, and whenever Trip 1 is, add the entry to the array.

Comment: how about you take some tutorials in sql? you'll find that the answer you're looking for is rather easy.

Comment: @Robotz91 Solved this yet?

Answer (score 0):

> The [**`SQL WHERE`**](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_where.asp) clause is used to specify a condition while fetching the data from a single table or by joining with multiple tables.

According to question, Your **`REQUIRED`** structure will be

```
  String str_Query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + FIELD_NAME + " = '" 1 "'";
```